# I can't use wifi or the internet on my machine. Ubuntu doesn't want to recognize my Rtl8812au wlan adapter

Tags: wireless

My only way of accessing the internet with my PC is the USB wifi adapter. It works on Windows but doesn't want to work on Ubuntu. I have no way of connecting to the internet unless I switch to windows.

I am too far away ot be able to utilize ether net cables.

Anyone got some drivers, etc for the adapter and a good way of installing them without me needing an ether net cord?

Comment: Can you use USB tethering with a phone?

Comment: Ethernet cables do support connections of 100 meters. You are over a 100 meters away from the router?

Comment: I don't have a 100 meter cord

Comment: I can't tether neither

Comment: I think some of you are forgetting that this is a dual boot setup. And I mentioned that it works fine with windows. Can't any of you utilize an idea that would use that to help get the drivers onto Ubuntu and install them. I can't access the github repository.

Comment: You can use your phone as a USB modem. You don't need a cord for that.

Comment: I still can't do that

Answer (score 0):

This [Github](https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au)
 Repository should work. There’s been quite a few issues with your WLAN adapter on Ubuntu, so its not going to work without some apparent tweaks. The best option I can think of is using the Github repo and hoping for the best. Since this is. A dual boot setup, I would clone the repository from your Windows computer, and then copy it onto a USB drive that can be accessed in Linux.

Comment: @kravchynko Why can’t you access the repo? The link works fine for me. Go onto Windows, considering you have dual boot, and clone it there. Then just copy the master branch using a USB stick or something on your Linux machine.

Answer (score 0):

Wicd Network manger on my Ub 19.1 connects and finds connections when Ubuntu can't.  Had no issues in the begining with 18.04 but did later.  Almost gave up on Ubuntu, till i realized the 802.1x supplicant error was causing Ubuntu to not see the connections or allow me to change to them.  Sometimes cmd for stopping and restarting networkmanager helped temporarily to see the connections again.